# how to check if a url is an image url with php?

Tags: php, image, validation, url, filenames

I need to check the url is image url or not? How can i do this?

Examples :

- [`http://www.google.com/`](http://www.google.com/) **is not** an image url.
- [`http://www.hoax-slayer.com/images/worlds-strongest-dog.jpg`](http://www.hoax-slayer.com/images/worlds-strongest-dog.jpg) **is** an image url.
- [`https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.jpg`](http://www.hoax-slayer.com/images/worlds-strongest-dog.jpg) **is not** an image url.
- [`http://www.google.com/profiles/c/photos/private/AIbEiAIAAABECK386sLjh92M4AEiC3ZjYXJkX3Bob3RvKigyOTEzMmFmMDI5ODQ3MzQxNWQxY2VlYjYwYmE2ZTA4YzFhNDhlMjBmMAEFQ7chSa4PMFM0qw02kilNVE1Hpw`](http://www.google.com/profiles/c/photos/private/AIbEiAIAAABECK386sLjh92M4AEiC3ZjYXJkX3Bob3RvKigyOTEzMmFmMDI5ODQ3MzQxNWQxY2VlYjYwYmE2ZTA4YzFhNDhlMjBmMAEFQ7chSa4PMFM0qw02kilNVE1Hpw) **is** an image url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check whether image exists on remote URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363925/check-whether-image-exists-on-remote-url) and on a more general level [How can one check to see if a remote file exists using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [best way to determine if a URL is an image in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676949/best-way-to-determine-if-a-url-is-an-image-in-php)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to be absolutely sure, and your PHP is enabled for remote connections, you can just use

```
getimagesize('url');
```

If it returns an array, it is an image type recognized by PHP, even if the image extension is not in the url (per your second link). You have to keep in mind that this method will make a remote connection for each request, so perhaps cache urls that you already probed in a database to lower connections.

Comment: Be sure to sanitize the URL if you do this!  Or better yet, use `curl`, which can't (shouldn't?) access the filesystem.

Comment: This doesn't executes commandos, it opens up the file and reads the header of the file. Can you explain me where the danger lies if someone would give say like /etc/passwd as the link? The function would just return FALSE.

Comment: It's a security risk nonetheless.  What if `getimagesize` contained a bug?  What if @Giffary decided to get more information from the image, and this gave more information to a potential hacker?  I don't know, but IMO it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: @Strager I couldn't agree more about better being safe than sorry, it's way too easy to leave a security hole. I was just wondering if there's a particular reason you made that statement.

Comment: false positive with https://pictures.content4us.com/products_high_res/153907z.eps.JPG

Answer (score 12):

You can send a [HEAD request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) to the server and then check the Content-type. This way you at least know what the server "thinks" what the type is.

Answer (score 6):

You can check if a url is an image by using the getimagesize function like below.

```
function validImage($file) {
   $size = getimagesize($file);
   return (strtolower(substr($size['mime'], 0, 5)) == 'image' ? true : false);  
}

$image = validImage('http://www.example.com/image.jpg');
echo 'this image ' . ($image ? ' is' : ' is not') . ' an image file.';
```

Comment: First time I've seen ['mime']. Do you know of somewhere that I can read up more on what it is and does?

Comment: @TrevorW I think there should be some information about it on the getimagesize function page http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: Sadly, sometimes extensions lie :'(

Answer (score 3):

i think that the idea is to get a content of the header url via curl

and check the headers

After calling `curl_exec()` to get a web page, call `curl_getinfo()` to get the content type string from the HTTP header

look how to do it in this link :

http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/06/php_tip_how_get_web_page_content_type#IfyouareusingCURL

Comment: Great link for other methods too!

Answer (score 3):

Can use this:

```
$is = @getimagesize ($link);
if ( !$is ) $link='';
elseif ( !in_array($is[2], array(1,2,3))   ) $link='';
elseif ( ($is['bits']>=8) ) $srcs[] = $link;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way that requires curl, but is faster than getimagesize, as it does not download the whole image. 
Disclaimer: it checks the headers, and they are not always correct.

```
function is_url_image($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $headers = array();
        foreach(explode("\n",$output) as $line){
            $parts = explode(':' ,$line);
            if(count($parts) == 2){
                $headers[trim($parts[0])] = trim($parts[1]);
            }

        }

        return isset($headers["Content-Type"]) && strpos($headers['Content-Type'], 'image/') === 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $filename)));
switch($ext)
{
case 'jpg':
///Blah
break;
}
```

Hard version (just trying)

```
//Turn off E_NOTICE reporting first
if(getimagesize($url) !== false)
{
//Image
}
```

Comment: `Turn off E_NOTICE reporting first`  Why not use the `@` operator if it's necessary?