# php get original image type

Tags: php, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to determine whether or not a file is an image in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405801/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-whether-or-not-a-file-is-an-image-in-php)

So if I rename an image file extension from a .jpg to a .png it will still be a .jpg image (if you right click and view image info it says so).

I am running a script that will convert anything that isn't a .jpg to a .jpg file. But now if I rename a file extension to something it isn't e.g. a .jpg to a .png it will try and convert the .png to a .jpg and it will return this error

> Warning: imagecreatefrompng() [function.imagecreatefrompng]:
>   '../../../assets/users/64/photos/26/737303.jpg' is not a valid PNG
>   file in
>   /home/iforumiz/public_html/buddyweb/assets/scripts/ak_php_img_lib_1.0.php
>   on line 33

So I need a way to find out the original file extension.