# How to check if image URL exists inside a loop of a foreach() in PHP?

Tags: php, url

EDITED:

1 - the `$search_result['image']` prints urls like: http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/wallpapers/21/7/wallpaper-sunset-images-back-217159.jpg

2 - Tried removing the include and placing the codes directly in the screenshots.php but I had no changes at all.

3 - Figured that maybe I can't request functions because of the foreach loop, so i changed it to `while($search_result, mysqli_fetch_array())` and making the sql consult as `mysqli_query` but the page won't load

I've been searching this in google for two days and couldn't make it work and a friend of mine told me about this website, and how it works, so... To the point:

I'm trying to check if the image URL exists and if does it returns the src of the image as the url itself, if the image URL no longer exists, or never did, the image src will change to one default.

The thing is that all the URLs are in the database...
Here is my php codes:

**screenshots.php**

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="dv_alb_pics" id="alb_ev_pics">';
    include('scripts/sug.php');
    echo $evs_content.'</div>';
?>
```

**sug.php**

```
<?php
    $images_search = $SQL->query("SELECT * FROM `screenshots` WHERE `section` = '1' AND `status` = '1' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 50;")->fetchAll();
    $evs_content .= '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>';
                foreach($images_search as $search_result) {
                    if(file_exists($search_result['image'])) {
                        $img_source = $search_result['image'];
                    } else {
                        $img_source = 'images/none.png';
                    }
                    $evs_content .= '<div class="ss_picture_rightside"><img class="ss_p_img_rightside" src="'.$img_source.'"></div>';
                }
            $evs_content .= '</td>
        </tr>
    </table>';
?>
```

While I was searching I saw in a post a guy saying that `file_exists()` works for URLs in php 5+

Turns out that he was probably wrong because It's not working at all

I also tried some `CURL` methods but when I use `CURL` inside the `foreach()` my screenshots page doesn't loads

I would appreciate any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: You have to use the absolute path with `file_exists`.

Comment: pls point out what in *$img_source*

Comment: What do you store in `$search_result['image']` is it just `file.jpg` or `path/to/file.jpg`

Comment: @donald123 Edited, thanks! the `$search_result['image']` prints an url

Comment: Technically you could avoid all this palaver with a simple JS `on error` type call...

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676949/best-way-to-determine-if-a-url-is-an-image-in-php

Comment: thanks @donald123 I'll try the method in the link and be right back

Comment: I have placed the function given in the link you sent above the `foreach()` and when I use the function `isImage($search_result['image'])` the page doesn't loads, same thing that happened when I tried the CURL method

Comment: @b0s3 thanks for your comment, would you please explain that to me?

Answer (score 0):

Replace following code in sug.php:-

```
foreach($images_search as $search_result) {
                    if(file_exists($search_result['image'])) {
                        $img_source = $search_result['image'];
                    } else {
                        $img_source = 'images/none.png';
                    }
                    $evs_content .= '<div class="ss_picture_rightside"><img class="ss_p_img_rightside" src="'.$img_source.'"></div>';
                }
```

with

```
foreach($images_search as $search_result) {
                    if (getimagesize($search_result['image']) !== false) {
                        $img_source = $search_result['image'];
                    } else {
                        $img_source = 'images/none.png';
                    }
                    $evs_content .= '<div class="ss_picture_rightside"><img class="ss_p_img_rightside" src="'.$img_source.'"></div>';
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the page is not loading with the `getimagesize()` function, actually none function worked so far inside the `foreach()`... Any ideas?

Comment: Could you print_R($search_result); ?

Comment: yea ofc 

 Array ( [id] => 6 [0] => 6 [account_id] => 2 [1] => 2 [title] => test picture [2] => test picture [location] => some place [3] => some place [world_id] => 0 [4] => 0 [description] => picture description [5] => picture description [image] => http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/wallpapers/21/7/wallpaper-sunset-images-back-217159.jpg [6] => http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/wallpapers/21/7/wallpaper-sunset-images-back-217159.jpg [date] => 1437117627 [7] => 1437117627 [status] => 1 [8] => 1 [section] => 1 [9] => 1 )

Comment: there are other results in the `print_R` but they are just copies of each other

Comment: in your screenshots.php file before including sug.php file just declare $evs_content = "";

Comment: Thanks again for your comment, I noticed the lack of it a few minutes ago and tried that but no changes at all