# check if link is image and also get image content in single request

Tags: php

Right now my code is below.Which I believe sends two request to Image url

```
if(getimagesize($imgurl)) // request 1
{

$imgget = file_get_contents("$imgurl"); // request 1
//other operations done here..
}
```

how can I check if its valid image and If its valid image get its contents in single request.

i.e., something like below

```
 if($imgget = getimagesize($imgurl)) // request 1
    {

    //$imgget must have image contents  

    }
```

Comment: there's an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676949/best-way-to-determine-if-a-url-is-an-image-in-php

Comment: @JoulinRouge that just detects if its image..my question is different

Comment: sorry! However there are no other checks needed:
as stated in the documentation: "Some formats may contain no image or may contain multiple images. In these cases, getimagesize() might not be able to properly determine the image size. getimagesize() will return zero for width and height in these cases."  http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: Curl is the answer to this question. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=hMpCsfvi_3c

Comment: @JoulinRouge Its not about checking if its image.. actually getimagesize() download full image in order to check if its image..I wanna know if I can get the image content with one request

Comment: you can do smething like this:

$img = '/my/folder/image.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($imgurl));

and then check if image.gif is a proper image

Comment: seems like good idea joulinrouge.. can you answer..so i can accept