# How to run url in php script and get response?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have set of records like this,

```
-------------------------------------------------
id_detail  |        id_url          |  id_name  |
-------------------------------------------------
   43454   |  xyz.com/xxx/yyyy.jpg  |   yyyyy   |
   43674   |  xyz.com/zzzz/ddd.jpg  |   rrrr    |
   48884   |  xyz.com/aaaa/eee.jpg  |   mmmm    |
   ....
   ....
   49994   |  xyz.com/cccc/fff.jpg  |   uuuu    |
-------------------------------------------------
```

now i need to run this url in while loop and if the images loads then i have to store respose as NO & if url resturn 404 then i have to store YES. Could anyone help me on it ? Please tell me how to get run url in php or curl and get response.

Sorry if my question was basic, i tried to get some idea on google but couldn't find so posting here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure but may be you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php  ??

Comment: Please check this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676949/best-way-to-determine-if-a-url-is-an-image-in-php)

Comment: Refer this SO answer to check whether the url exists or not http://stackoverflow.com/a/2280413/6374322

Comment: thanks @SanojSharma , madan , vignesh

Comment: @Munna, did you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can use curl and because of your condition you must get http header with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);` and if you don't need image you can prevent to get body with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);`. after set this option you get response like :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 29 Sep 2016 15:17:34 GMT Server: Apache Last-Modified: Sun, 15 Nov 2015 06:45:21 GMT Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 50822 Content-Type: image/png Age: 423 Expires: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 06:06:51 GMT
```

if status code is 200 like above its exist but if status code 404 its not exist.

the final code something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"xyz.com/xxx/yyyy.jpg");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $server_output;
```

you must read first character of a $server_output ('HTTP/1.1 200 OK' = exist) or ('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' = not exist)